# Trouble implementing NavigationView - Sc.View is not observable

Tags: javascript, navigation, key-value-observing, sproutcore, sproutcore-views

When I try to push a view on the view stack of my NavigationView using

```
MyApp.getPath('mainPage.mainPane.content.nav').push(MyApp.MyView);
```

It gives me this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (props) {
      this.__sc_super__ = ret.prototype;
      return this._object_init(props);
    } has no method 'get'
```

Obviously, SC.View is not KVO compliant. Then is it a bug in the SproutCore framework? Because they do this in the SC.NavigationView source:

```
view.get("topToolbar"); // with `view` being the view I passed in as shown above
```

`MyApp.MyView` looks like this:

```
MyApp.MyView = SC.View.extend({
    childViews: 'search results'.w(),

    search: SC.TextFieldView.design({
        layout: { centerX: 0, top: 40, width: 400, height: 30 },
        hint: "Search"
    }),

    results: SC.TemplateView.design({
        templateName: 'results'
    }),

    topToolbar: SC.NavigationBarView.design({
        childViews: ['title'],
        layout: { height: 44 },
        title: SC.LabelView.design({
            controlSize: SC.LARGE_CONTROL_SIZE,
            layout: { width: 100, height: 24, centerX: 0, centerY: 0 },
            value: 'Title'
        })
    })
});
```

But I think the SproutCore developers are way smarter and more experienced than I am, so it's probably something I did.

**Why doesn't my `SC.View` subclass have a `get()` method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your view hasn't been created yet, so it's still a class rather than an instance. Classes don't have .get, only instances. If you're getting fancy (definitely encouraged :) ) with passing views around, rather than simply letting the childView hierarchy handle them, you have to create them as well. Try passing in MyApp.MyView.create() instead.

Comment: Ok, it came up with another error message: `NavigationBarView requires SC.Animatable. Please make your app or framework require the animation framework. CRASH.` Well, I can't even find SC.Animatable in the docs, so I'm stuck now.

Comment: This is a separate issue and might deserve its own question. At any rate, two-part answer here. Part 1: you can include non-default framework by editing your app's Buildfile so that the "required" bit looks like this - :required => [:sproutcore, :"sproutcore/animation"]

Comment: Part 2: The animation framework is an old, deprecated animation framework that's still available but will be removed soon... meaning that this view is badly out of date! I know that @publickeating has been doing some work on a new, updated version; you should reach out to him on the IRC channel and see if the code is stable enough to share yet.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I had asked you. I poked around a bit already on the IRC channel (I'm `SproutLearner` there, IRC doesn't accept numerical usernames) and opened a thread on the Google Group. But thanks for the tip for reaching out to publickeating.